# Silverlight UserControl not displaying

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, user-controls

I have a simple `UserControl` that I want to display in my stackpanel programmatically
.

When I do, the UC does not show on the screen. If I drag a single instance from the toolbox it works fine.

**The User Control is XAML is**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MYProj.Controls.SpecialNumberOption"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Viewbox>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="200" Height="300">
        <Button x:Name="buttonMe" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Height="150" Style="{StaticResource NumberButtonStyle}" Click="buttonMe_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="subText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,165,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="125" Width="180" FontStyle="Italic" TextAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

**The Codebehind**

```
public partial class SpecialNumberOption : UserControl
{


    public event RoutedEventHandler Click;



    public SpecialNumberOption()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        this.applyStyle();
    }

    public SpecialNumberOption(SurveyQuestionOption option)
    {
        this.buttonMe.Content = option.Text;
        this.subText.Text = option.SubText;

        this.applyStyle();
    }


    private void applyStyle()
    {

        this.buttonMe.FontSize = 26;
        this.buttonMe.Background = standardBackground;
        this.buttonMe.Foreground = standardForecolor;

    }

    ///Raise the event to the outside

    private void buttonMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Click(this, e);
    }



}
```

**Implementation**

This is how Im adding the control

```
    foreach (var y in x.Options)
    {

            //Create new instance from An object
            var r = new SpecialNumberOption(y);

            // Set visibility
            r.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;


            r.IsEnabled = false;

            //Assign the event handler
            r.Click += r_Click;

            //This is my stackpanel
            listOptions.Children.Add(r);


            ....
    }




    //Handle the click event
    void r_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SpecialNumberOption o = (SpecialNumberOption)e.OriginalSource;
        ....

    }
```

**Update**

I found when I use the alternate Constructor this is when it ceases to work.
I have to use the default constructor. Is this normal?

Comment: r.IsEnabled = false; try that as true

Comment: Yeah I tried that too and no go, the IsEnabled should just allow/prevent the Control to be interacted with. Visually it should appear.

Comment: rather in a foreach loop cant you try adding one control dynamically?

Comment: I did that to test as well but it seems the only problem is when I try to add this control programmaticly, its fine if I do it in XAML at design time.

Comment: The issue only occurs when I use a constructor where I pass in an object.

Comment: ohh InitializeComponent(); is missing in that constructor. Before initializing the component you are trying to set text for the controlls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not checked all of your posted code for correctness but here is the issue with your constructors: you must call `InitializeComponent` (and it must happen before you access any named elements)

here is a version with a fix:

```
public SpecialNumberOption()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.applyStyle();
}

public SpecialNumberOption(SurveyQuestionOption option) : this () //will call the empty default constructor
{
    this.buttonMe.Content = option.Text;
    this.subText.Text = option.SubText;
}
```

Remark: I consider it bad style for controls to have more than the empty default constructor.
The parameters should be set via a property setter. It enable you and whoever will be reusing your control to use and parameterize it in xaml.

Comment: thanks, I didnt know I could call the default constructor like you have above. Im new to Silverlight so Im used to creating alternate constructors.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it is totally OK to have multiple constructors for your own types - but when you derive from `control` you create a special kind of type: a type that will be used declaratively in your `xaml` markup where no constructor parameters can be used.
So one of my personal heuristics for "doing the right thing" is: types derived from DependencyObject must not use constructor parameters. But as always, it is only my personal heuristic, and it can be wrong - it is just my trick to make me write my code in a way that makes me feel safe.